# Prometheus : how do i group by with 2 different metrics and show in table

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have 2 different metrics : metric_a with a field eonid metric_b with a field eonid .

example of success.

```html
metric_a :
eonid = 123, appname = app5
eonid = 123, appname = app1
metric_b :

eonid = 235, appname = app3
eonid=234 ,appname = app4
eonid=234 ,appname = app4
```

I'm trying to show table  based on the  eonid.
for example table data show

```html
eoinid app-name  metricname
123    app5      metric_a
123    app1      metric_a
235    app3      metric_b
234    app4      metric_b
```

How can I achieve that by using group by.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming question about table in Grafana:

1. Add both your metrics to panel. In query options select:

   - Legent: Verbose
   - Type: Instant
2. On tab Transform add transforms:

   - Series to Rows
   - Extract fields:

     - Source: Metric
   - Organize fields - organize according to your taste